# Is it safe to store phone numbers straight to Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

For an app I am building, I want users to be able to find each other through their contacts. This would require me to save a user's phone number and name to Firestore, which could then be found by other users that already have that phone number in their device contacts. Is this safe enough for phone numbers or should I somehow encrypt the numbers before uploading?

My security rules would be to allow read/write if request.auth != null

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-fix-firestore-error-permission-denied-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-777d591f404) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to store phone numbers straight in Firestore?

Yes, as long as you secure your database using [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

> I want users to be able to find each other through their contacts.

That's perfectly possible, using a `whereField` function call.

> This would require me to save a user phone number and name to Firestore, which could then be found by other users that already have that phone number in their device contacts.

Yes, in code it might look like this:

```
db.collection("users").whereField("contacts", arrayContains: "somePhoneNumber")
    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            }
        }
}
```

Assuming that you have an array of `contacts`, you can simply use `arrayContains` and you'll get all users in the "users" collection that have in the `contacts` array a particular phone number.

> Is this safe enough for phone numbers or should I somehow encrypt the numbers before uploading?

You can encrypt the numbers if you want, but I don't think that in your case is quite necessary.

> My security rules would be allow read/write if request.auth != null

Those rules allow **all** users who are authenticated to read and write from/into your database. If you want, for example, to only get the user's friends, you can enforce that too. How? Simply by creating an array of friends and then return results of users who are friends with each other.